# NSMetadataQuery gets multiple (identical) DidUpdateNotification

Tags: ios, icloud, nsmetadataquery

I'm working on verifying an app works on iOS 11.

On iOS 10, I start an `NSMetadataQuery` on the scope `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope`, and I get exactly one `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification`.  And that's it.  That's the *only* notification received due to the query.

However, on iOS 11, I again get exactly one `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification`, but in addition I'm getting what appears to be an infinite number of `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification`s, coming in at an approximate rate of 1 every second, all of them with an *identical* payload.

I will admit that I'm unfamiliar enough with iCloud syncing that I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, but I'm pretty sure that's not correct behavior.

Is this a bug in iOS 11?  Can anyone point me in a direction to track down what's going on?

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same thing!

Comment: I think other people on the apple dev forums have made some progress with this... https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/91159. My code is derived from Ray Wenderlich's sample, if it sees a metadata update it opens the document, reads the data and closes the document. That triggers a metadata update and an infinite loop. p.s. it shouldn't crash though, you may also have a memory leak or abandoned memory.

Comment: also... https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/277699#277699

Comment: you'll need to be signed in to read them

Comment: It appears to me this is still a bug in iOS 12.1/XCode 10.1